# How to improve efficiency in a count on a temp table

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to add a count field to an access table that increments for every duplicated record in another field, in chronological order.

So the "counter" increases by one, every time "uniquecase" duplicates. This is also in chronological order so the duplicates are numbered 1 upwards, starting with the earliest duplicate (eg.)

```
Counter | UniqueCase | ResolvedDate
1          3312        01/01/2018
1          6374        01/01/2018
2          6374        02/01/2018
1          8546        15/03/2019
2          8546        18/03/2019
3          8546        12/05/2019
```

The query below works for this situation:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM [COMEBACKTEST2] 
     AS TMP
   WHERE [UNIQUECASE]=[COMEBACKTEST2].[UNIQUECASE] 
     AND [KEY]<=[COMEBACKTEST2].[KEY]
  ) AS [COUNTER],
  *
INTO [Comeback 3]
FROM COMEBACKTEST2
ORDER BY COMEBACKTEST2.UniqueCase, COMEBACKTEST2.ResolvedDate;
```

When I "view" this, it takes a couple of seconds, I can see the results are correct (I scanned a few thousand lines). However when attempting to "run", it will not complete, even after leaving it several hours.

Is there a more efficient version of this query, as in it's current state it seems too intensive to actually work?

- There are approximately 130k rows in [COMEBACKTEST2]
- I've tried indexing
- I've tried just querying rather than adding

I'm guessing it needs a different approach altogether?
Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks!

Example above lost formatting sorry :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IAc.png)

Comment: Please provide precise details, not summaries for critical details.  Describing the precise index(es) which you tried is just as important as showing the SQL code, especially if the question is about query efficiency.

Comment: FYI.  Formatting can be preserved by using the proper "markdown".  The question edit box has a toolbar with various formatting buttons.  You can also click the "?" button/icon on the toolbar for more help on formatting the document.

Answer (score 1):

The Access SQL optimizer is not sophisticated and so it most likely will re-run the nested query for every row of the outer query, thus the long amount of time to run the entire SELECT INTO.  It is generally better to avoid nested queries in the SELECT clause and instead join on an aggregate query.  The difficulty comes in *counting records based on an inequality*.  For that we leverage a cross join (i.e. Cartesian product), then group on key values only on one side of the product.

```
SELECT COUNTER.Sequence, t3.*
INTO [Comeback 3]
FROM COMEBACKTEST2 AS t3 JOIN
  (SELECT Count(t1.KEY) AS Sequence, t1.UNIQUECASE, t1.KEY
   FROM COMEBACKTEST2 AS t1, COMEBACKTEST2 AS t2
   WHERE ((t2.UNIQUECASE = t1.[UNIQUECASE]) AND (t2.KEY <= t1.[KEY]))
   GROUP BY t1.UNIQUECASE, t1.KEY
  ) AS [COUNTER]
  ON (t3.UNIQUECASE= COUNTER.UNIQUECASE) AND (t3.KEY = COUNTER.KEY)
ORDER BY t3.UNIQUECASE, COUNTER.Sequence;
```

It is still best to have appropriate indexes.  In this case, ensure that there are *separate* indexes on [UniqueCase] and [Key].

The above form will be necessary if you have other columns that you want returned with the example columns.  However, as long as [ResolvedDate] corresponds chronologically with the [Key] values as stated, then all posted columns can be obtained in a single query:

```
SELECT Count(t1.KEY) AS Sequence, t1.UNIQUECASE, 
    t1.KEY, Max(t2.ResolvedDate) AS ResolvedDate
FROM COMEBACKTEST2 AS t1, COMEBACKTEST2 AS t2
WHERE ((t2.UNIQUECASE = t1.[UNIQUECASE]) AND (t2.KEY <= t1.[KEY]))
GROUP BY t1.UNIQUECASE, t1.KEY
ORDER BY t1.UNIQUECASE, t1.KEY;
```